# How to ensure the same element doesn't appear twice in an array

Tags: java

I have an array of files names ending with either .xml or .gxml.
I am putting each element into another array.
I need to ensure that the same file name is not added twice.

So the real question is how do I ensure the same element is not added twice into an array?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Set` instead of array for processing, to ensure it doesn't appear twice

```
Set<String> fileNames = new HashSet<String>();
fileNames.add("1.txt");
fileNames.add("2.txt");
// not necessarily in that order with HashSet
System.out.println(fileNames); //[1.txt,2.txt]
fileNames.add("1.txt");// it will not add this one
System.out.println(fileNames); //[1.txt,2.txt]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array each time you add the item, and compare the two. If they are the same, don't add the new one.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

    if (object = array[i]) {
       //DONT ADD THE OBJECT HERE
    else {
        //add the object
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a set is the best option.
Another way can be to use a HashMap with file name as key and file object as value.

```
HashMap<String,File> fileMap = new HashMap<String,File> ();

if (fileMap.get("fileName")==null)
fileMap.put("fileName",file)
```